# Merge Data Based on last three Characters in R

Tags: r, merge

I want to merge Airport_Code.1 & Airport_Code.2 by the last three 
  letters of Airport_Code.2. If the last 3 letters from Airport_Code.1 
  matches Airport_Code.2 print Airport_Code.1

```
        Airport_Code.1       Airport_Code.2      
    1       AJFK                 BWI              
    2       ABWI                 JSJ              
    3       BJSJ                 JFk              
    4       ....                 ...             
    5       ....                 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

some data:

```
a = sample(LETTERS, 20)
b = sample(LETTERS, 20)
c = sample(LETTERS, 20)
d = sample(LETTERS, 20)

Airport_Code.2 = paste0(a,b,c)
Airport_Code.1 = paste0(d,a,b,c)

df = data.frame(Airport_Code.1, Airport_Code.2)

df$Airport_Code.1 = as.character(df$Airport_Code.1)
df$Airport_Code.2 = as.character(df$Airport_Code.2)
```

Find out the number of letters in Airport_Code.1 with `nchar`, and use `substring` to isolate the last 3 letters and use `ifelse` to return Airport_Code.1 if a match and NA if not.

```
n_air = nchar(df$Airport_Code.1)
Result_Airport = ifelse(substring(Airport_Code.1,  n_air-2, n_air) ==  Airport_Code.2, Airport_Code.1, NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

`purrr::map` solution

```
df$Result <- map_chr(1:nrow(df), ~ifelse(grepl(df[.x,2], df[.x,1]), as.character(df[.x,1]), NA))
```

Output

```
  Airport_Code.1 Airport_Code.2 Result_Airport Result
1           AJFK            JFK           AJFK   AJFK
2           ABWI            BWI           ABWI   ABWI
3           BJSJ            JSJ           BJSJ   BJSJ
```

Your data

```
df <- read.table(text="Airport_Code.1       Airport_Code.2     Result_Airport 
   AJFK                 JFK              AJFK
  ABWI                 BWI              ABWI
  BJSJ                 JSJ              BJSJ", header=TRUE)
```